# Underscore.js New Array of Objects with child arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have an array of objects in the following structure

```
var projects = [
    {id:'1',name:'project1', parentid:"null"},
    {id:'2',name:'project2', parentid:"null"},
    {id:'3',name:'subproject1', parentid:"1"},
    {id:'4',name:'subproject2', parentid:"1"},
    {id:'5',name:'subproject3', parentid:"2"}
];
```

I would like to make a new array with the following structure

```
var newProjects = [
    {text:'project1', children:[
        {id:'3',name:'subproject1', parentid:"1"},
        {id:'4',name:'subproject2', parentid:"1"}
    ]},
    {text:'project2', children:[
        {id:'5',name:'subproject3', parentid:"2"}
    ]}
]
```

I have been able to do this using a bunch of loops and if statements but would like to clean it up by using Underscore.js but been unable to do so. could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show us your bunch of loops!

Comment: Why did `name` change to `text`? And where did the `id` go?

Comment: I work on a system that will not allow me to copy my code over to the internet

Comment: Seems like a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user1720275: Sorry, then we hardly can help with transforming your code to use underscore. At least you would need to tell us what your loops and if-statements do, e.g. by posting pseudocode.

Comment: name changed to text because I am using select2 to group the object in a select box and that is the format that is used to show the project names as group headers. the id was no longer necessary because it was just being used as a header.

Comment: Without seeing your code, how are we supposed to know what's wrong with it? You don't expect that we just write an implementation in underscore, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data given, you can probably get away with using a simple `groupBy` and `map`.

Something like this:

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(projects, 'parentid');
var newProjects = _.map(grouped['null'], function (project, id) {
    return {
        text: project.name,
        children: grouped[project.id]
    };
});
```

If you have deeper nesting, you'll need to work out a more robust solution, but this should give you an idea on what to do.